# `browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener` not working. Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

`chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` works for me. But when I migrate to `webextension-polyfill`, I got

```
browser-polyfill.js:1183 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
    at B (browser-polyfill.js:1183:20)
```

Code, *src/pages/background/index.ts*:

```js
console.log('background script loaded');

import browser from 'webextension-polyfill';

browser.contextMenus.create({
    id: 'translate-selection',
    title: 'Translate Selection',
    contexts: ['selection']
});


browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    sendResponse(translateText(message.text));
});
browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(async (info, tab) => {
    console.log(info);
    console.log(tab);

    if (info.menuItemId === 'translate-selection') {
        const textToTranslate = info.selectionText;
        const response = await browser.runtime.sendMessage({ text: textToTranslate });
        console.log(response);
    }
});
async function translateText(text: string): Promise<string> {
    return "translated text"
}
```

Seems `browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener` does not listen.

I tried:

- Use port, not working
- Put  `browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener` into `content.ts`. Not working.

Comment: 1) Judging by the code you use sendMessage to send to onMessage in the same script. This won't work. You should directly call translateText from onClicked. 2) If you want to send to a tab then use browser.tabs.sendMessage. 3) If it's ManifestV3 there should be no need for browser polyfill.

Comment: I want to send it to my popup to show result. Also tried different scripts which also doesn't work

Comment: The popup cannot receive messages if it's not shown.